# Converting .Net 1.1 websites to 4.0

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have some .NET 1.1 websites that need to be converted into 4.0. I don't want to change the functionality or the design I just want them to be converted to 4.0 so that future edits can be made easily as working in 1.1 is not easy. What is the beast approach that I should follow for this purpose.

Answer (score 5):

Use the converter tool in VS 2012 and then clean up any errors after the build.

Comment: and what is this converter tool?

Comment: When you'll open the project in VS it checks for lower version. if it finds then it ask you to convert via Convert Tool. it comes automatically in case of lower versions..

Answer (score 3):

just put the targetFramework element in the webconfig

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.0">
```

by doing this your website will run in `Asp.Net 4.0` and because you dont want to change anything else just leave everything else as it is
because `.net 4.0` is backward compatible i dont think you would face any errors

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to read [Microsoft .NET Framework 1.1 and 2.0 Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms994381.aspx).

After that, be sure to check .NET 4.0 migration issues document.

Read [C# in Depth](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182471) from [Jon Skeet](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/8958/jon-skeet) that describes all new features for each version of C#.

Comment: why he needs to learn about new features? and your second link points to nothing